# Highcharts pie chart slice colour intensity using colorValue

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am trying to achieve the same thing as seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/treemap-coloraxis

Except with a pie chart instead.

I have it set up like so:

```
 $('#expenditurePie').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                backgroundColor: '#121212',
                height: 322,
                className: 'summary-chart-right'
            },
            title: null,
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    borderColor: '#000',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: false
                }
            },
            colorAxis: {
                minColor: '#FFFFFF',
                maxColor: '#FF0000'
            },
            series: response
        });
```

A sample of response data:

```
...
{name: "Leisure", y: 143.55, colorValue: 3}
...
```

It isn't working and the pie chart colours are their default.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.colorValue), colorValue is only available on TreeMaps.

However, you can do a similar thing without much difficulty. Instead of `colorValue`, use `color`, and then call to a function to get a value. Here's a quick-and-dirty example that can be improved in various ways depending on exactly what behavior you want:

```
var getColor = function (step,stepCount) {
    var scaledHex = Math.floor(255*step/(stepCount+1)).toString(16);
    console.log(scaledHex);
    return '#FF'+scaledHex+scaledHex;
};
```

And

```
...
{name: "Leisure", y: 143.55, color: getColor(1,3)}
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Lnzcnx6/

Comment: Thanks. The series data is determined in PHP so I would just have to adapt what you wrote in JS.

Comment: You might not even have to do that, depending on how your code is structured. You can have the PHP create the series object, with the function call in it as in my example, and highcharts will call the javascript function on the fly as it renders. Moving the logic into PHP would work too, though.