# How can I generate n amount of colors within a range of two given colors?

Tags: javascript, colors

I am trying to dynamically calculate a range of colors for a pie chart in JavaScript. I need the colors to step gradually from the Start Blue to the End Blue, and given the fact that I don't know how many pie slices there will be, I need to calculate it based on the value of a variable: `n`.

I found a great answer to this question in Java here: [How to dynamically compute a list of colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403826/how-to-dynamically-compute-a-list-of-colors)

But I'm not 100% sure how this translates into JavaScript. I also need them to be in order (lightest to darkest / darkest to lightest) in an array format.

```
var colorArray = [];
var startColor = #18AED5;`
var endColor   = #1E1E26;`
// Calculate Colors...`
```

If anyone could help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Give it a go, then we can help when you run into trouble. You'll learn much more from trying it yourself than you will from someone giving you a complete answer.

Comment: As @RGraham has said, try to do it by yourself first. StackOverflow is here to help if you do end up stuck somewhere specific in your code, but we're not here to do everything for you from scratch. (The Java question you linked isn't exactly the best example for this site)

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728212/highcharts-pie-chart-slice-colour-intensity-using-colorvalue/29735454#29735454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I created a little [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x6L1brry/)

**JS:**

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var a = b = c = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+a+','+b+','+c+')';
    a+=1;
    b+=2;
    c+=3;
}, 50);
```

It's easier to handle the dynamic color change with `rgb()` instead of the hex.

---

**Update:**

I was able to do as you wanted. To go from one color to another. [Demo2](https://jsfiddle.net/x6L1brry/3/)

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}

var dynamicColorChange = function (start, end, target) {
    var startRGB = hexToRgb(start),
        endRGB = hexToRgb(end),
        si = setInterval(function () {
            if (startRGB.r < endRGB.r) {
                startRGB.r += 1;
            }else if(startRGB.r > endRGB.r){
            startRGB.r -= 1;
            }
            if (startRGB.g < endRGB.g) {
                startRGB.g += 1;
            }else if(startRGB.g > endRGB.g){
                startRGB.g -= 1;
            }
            if (startRGB.b < endRGB.b) {
                startRGB.b += 1;
            }else if(startRGB.b > endRGB.b){
                startRGB.b -= 1;
            }
            target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + startRGB.r + ',' + startRGB.g + ',' + startRGB.b + ')';
            if (startRGB.r == endRGB.r && startRGB.g == endRGB.g && startRGB.g == endRGB.g) {
                clearInterval(si);
            }
        }, 50);
    console.log(startRGB);
    console.log(endRGB);
};

dynamicColorChange('#18AED5', '#1E1E26', div);
```